# Spring boot 2.0.6 quartz missing org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SpringBeanJobFactory in war

Tags: java, spring-boot, war, quartz

Using spring boot war build during the start up of the application in the tomcat

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SpringBeanJobFactory.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
```

even though it exists as a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And also `spring-context-support`

There are no issues with spring boot jar build and run

How to fix the issue for the war deployment?

This is what I get when debugging jar file - maybe this might help: (with war file ClassNotFoundException)

[image]

Comment: The `SpringBeanJobFactory` is found in the `spring-context-support` dependency. What version are using?

Comment: +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz:jar:2.0.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile

Comment: the class is inside it. Spring boot jar file runs without an issue. The issue occurs only when I build it as war and deploy on the separate tomcat. However the dependency is present. Have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, it's just suggestion:

Try to add dependencies:

```
    <!--Quartz-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

NOTE: It's just a way to 'hot fix'. And it is not a complete solution.

Comment: I have these dependencies defined for both jar and war. Only version 2.3.0 instead of 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. As I was running Tomcat from the IntelliJ Idea and new dependencies introduced to the project were not reflected. Needed to remove and reimport war/war exploded into Tomcat configuration - no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following dependency (if you want you can set Spring version by yourself):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```